# Override ToString in NUnit without access to source code

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a class, `Foo`, from a third party library that I check for equality against another instance using NUnit,

```
Assert.AreEqual(foo1, foo2);
```

When the objects are different I get the expected failure,

```
Expected: Foo
But was: Foo
```

But the error message isn't very helpful. I know NUnit uses `ToString` to show the error message but I can't override that here.

Does NUnit provide an API to override this behaviour so I can supply my own `ToString` implementation? I can't see anything on the `Assert.AreEqual` and `Assert.That` APIs

Comment: Why not simply supply a custom error message to the `Assert.AreEqual` method (as third parameter)?

Comment: Yea that's an option, but I was hoping to not have to do that as my actual use case is more complex, using `CollectionAssert` so building up the message is going to be more work than just providing a ToString override

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add specific formatting code for any Type and NUnit will use it. See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#addformatter

This feature was added in NUnit 3.2.

Comment: So do you do this: `TestContext.AddFormatter(obj => { if (obj == null) { return ""; } var foo = obj as Foo; if (foo == null) { return obj.ToString(); } /* build string representation of foo here and return it */ });` I upvoted your answer but you could provide an example as a supplement to the link.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after, thanks. We're on an older version which is why I didn't see it on the API.

Comment: Following up on @JeppeStigNielsen 's reply, using another version of `AddFormatter` you can simply the code to `TestContext.AddFormatter<Foo>(obj => { var foo = obj as Foo; /* build string representation using variable foo here and return it */ });`

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a great approach, but you could wrap the values inside of another class, and override `ToString()` there. For instance, in your test fixture, create the following private class:

```
private class ValueWrapper
{
    private readonly OtherClass _wrapped;

    public ValueWrapper(OtherClass wrapped)
    {
        _wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // Compare the wrapped objects for equality.
        // This needs some beefing up for null checks, type checks, etc.
        return _wrapped.Equals(obj._wrapped);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "whatever you like";
    }
}
```

With this wrapper class in hand, you could then wrap your expected & actual values and pass this into the asserts. For a `CollectionAssert`, you'd do so by transforming each element in the collection into one of these, using a `Select()` LINQ clause.

Answer (score 1):

Using the accepted answer I put together the following code to json-serialize my failed constraints (using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)):

```
TestContext.AddFormatter(obj =>
{
    if (obj == null)
        return x => "";

    return x => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
});
```